# how serious is the risk for electro-static discharge damage?

Tags: static-discharge

when repairing computers and handling the various electronic parts inside, how serious is the risk that electro-static discharge damage will occur if one doesn't take precautions?

I have heard of many people that rouyinely repair/upgrade computers that do not take any precautions and they say they never had problems..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why should I not keep things producing static electricity near my computer cabinet?](http://superuser.com/questions/181687/why-should-i-not-keep-things-producing-static-electricity-near-my-computer-cabin)

Comment: I once destroyed a motherboard via ESD. walking across carpet without shoes (socks only) while carrying it was more than sufficient to prevent it from ever booting again. Nowadays I don't do repairs in rooms with carpet. it also depends on the components in question, and whether they have a power in them at the time. be careful with CPUs, and anything with a ROM, especially if the unit has a battery or charged capacitors.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to generalize. To even endanger components through electro-static discharge you need to be charged first. This can happen more likely when having carpet at home or wearing certain clothes that generate charges easier.

Personally, I never had a problem. The only precaution I usually take is to touch a grounded cable to remove any charges. I also never touch any components and only try to touch devices and components where it's safe.

Still, if you have a cable to attach to your wrist to keep you grounded while handling sensitive electronic components you should use it, else just be very careful. I don't think the chances of electro-static discharges are too great with the above hints in mind, but you can never rule them out if you're not constantly grounded.