# How can I make my laptop cooler and quieter?

Tags: laptop, cooling, noise

The laptop coolers on my Clevo W870CU are not very quiet, especially when gaming.

Is it possible to replace the laptop cooler with a quieter cooler that still has the same air flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get some canned air and just clean out the vents as best you can. This will often improve airflow and reduce friction on the existing fan enough to make a noticeable improvement in the noise level.

Answer (score 1):

it would be easier to get an external laptop fan. I have one made by antec that cools it down by quite a bit. The best thing about this is that they are easily replaceable, unlike laptop fans

Comment: How does this decrease the noise of the internal cooler? I also use my laptop on quite some different places which makes this not feasible, I've already learned to live with it but as I seen [a different question for PC](http://superuser.com/questions/337053/how-can-i-make-my-pc-cooler-and-quieter), I'm wondering if this is somehow possibility to be done with my laptop...

Comment: well by decreasing the temperature of the internals of your laptop, your fans will not need to work as hard and could potentially not need to run at full power. This would make the noise lower. Also as for the fans, there are plenty of portable solutions, do a search on amazon and see if anything fits your needs

Answer (score 1):

There are [some](http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/showthread.php?t=39547) [DIY](http://www.instructables.com/id/Watercooling-a-laptop-on-the-cheap/) projects that have liquid-cooling at their core. This obviously reduces the temperature, but a savvy hobbyist could simply modify the project to remove the fans completely and run only a liquid-cooling setup.

Obviously this renders the laptop more of a desktop, but it does answer the question. For a more portable solution, as the other answers state, a [good gaming laptop cooling pad](http://www.thermaltake.com/products-model.aspx?id=C_00001809) is the best option.

Comment: I've been browsing couple of reviews of cooling pads, they have zero impact on internal temps, except that they lift the laptop off of the desk, resulting in 1-3°C less just by this "passive" effect. Not worth the money in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In general: No. You buy/trash a laptop 'as it'. You can't 'mod' it. The only thing you can do is to buy an external cooler (fans). 
The other thing you can do is to open your laptop and 'clean' fans from dust.

Comment: I have a bare-bone laptop in which I am eligible to 'mod' things as much as I want to, it's out of warranty too. See [my comment to mugetsu's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/337578/how-can-i-make-my-laptop-cooler-and-quieter/337586#comment-368470) which explains why an external cooler is no real solution for me, I'm up for a hardware mod as that's necessary anyway but I don't know how to check if a given small fan would be more quiet but still produce the same air flow. Since I bought it I replaced most stuff in it, the fans still bug me...